# Deploy Angular2 in Jboss, How to?

Tags: angular, jboss

How to deploy an Angular 2 application on a Jboss application server, such as the WildFly server.

It's possible?

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The fact that you didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour pretty much assures us you didn't do any Internet research or read the Help FAQ before posting this question.  Question belongs in ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 is used to build Single Page Applications.
This means that eventually with Angular2 you produce a bundle of javascript, html5 and css that will be provided by a standard web server as static resources and executed in the browser.
Application Servers do not play any role in Angular 2 per se and there is no concept of 'deployment of Angular2apps on App Servers'.
Then, your angular app may well have to consume back end services, but this is another story